# How to read one line at a time in generated texts with request?

Tags: python, python-requests

In Python 3 I'm reading links with "fixed-width files". Example

```
import requests
pagina = requests.get('http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/consultas/download/F.K03200UF.D71214AC')
only_text = pagina.text

only_text
'0107398403000180BOI GORDO AGROPECUARIA COMERCIO E REPRESENTACOES LTDA - EPP                                                                                                                   \n02073984030001802              49SELMA ELIANA MEDEIROS RIBEIRO                                                                                                                                \n02073984030001802              22MARCELO LUIZ SANCHES                                                                                                                                         \n0103173169000131CONSELHO ESCOLAR BOM JESUS                        

...

\n0129235225000109MD CONFECCOES EIRELI - ME                                                                                                                                                     \n02292352250001092              65MARCELO AMARO DA SILVA                                                                                                                                       \n'
```

I need to read each line of "only_text" separately to extract strings in certain positions on each line

I've tried this, but the command takes one character at a time instead of each line

```
for linha in only_text:
    print(linha)

0
1
0
7
3
9
8
4
0
3
0
0
0
1
8
0
B
O
I
...
```

Please, how can I isolate and read each line separately?

Comment: split in "\n", have you tried this?

Comment: It works, thanks: lista_de_linha = only_text.split('\n') -> 
for linha in lista_de_linha:
    print(linha)